# Why isn't knownfolders works in winrt? Am I missing something?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-runtime

I'm working on a UWP project with a background Task involved.  The background task needs to check a specific file on the document library.

This code works perfectly.

```
  try
    {
        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
        SendToast(file.Path + file.Name + " - File Present");
    }
catch 
    {
        SendToast("Not Found");
    }
```

This one doesn't

```
  try
    {
        StorageFile file = await KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.GetFileAsync(fileName);
        SendToast(file.Path + file.Name + " - File Present");
    }
catch
    {
        SendToast("Not Found");
    }
```

I have also add the document library capability in the Package.appxmanifest

```
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <uap:Capability Name="documentsLibrary" />
  </Capabilities>
```

and this

```
<uap:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
  <uap:FileTypeAssociation Name=".txt">
    <uap:DisplayName>Text</uap:DisplayName>
    <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
      <uap:FileType>.log</uap:FileType>
    </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
  </uap:FileTypeAssociation>
</uap:Extension>
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: To add, I made sure my windows is updated up to Fall creator update 2017.

Comment: Any updates regarding this issue? I believe Breeze's answer already showed the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

UWP apps run sandboxed and have very limited access to the file system, `StorageItems`(i.e. `StorageFolder` and `StorageFile`) are the canonical storage identifiers for Windows Store apps, not the path.

The data that are stored in our local folder (`ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`), we can use the path, but if you use the `DocumentsLibrary`,`MusicLibrary`, we can not use the path to access the file, it refers to a non file-system location and The DocumentsLibrary capability does not grant the app direct file system access. See [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) and Rob's [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2012/12/04/skip-the-path-stick-to-the-storagefile/) to learn more about file access and using path in Windows store apps.